# changing facebook Open Graph protocol value when button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below are codes that I want to change when I click jquery button?

```
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    ...
  </head>
```

I have a question if is possible to make this when share button click and the change value on  Open Graph protocol will get in share link?

Answer (score 2):

Changing these with JavaScript will not change what shows on Facebook. Facebook's method of retrieving these values will ignore any JavaScript on the page and parse whatever is in the source.

Comment: I guess there is also no other way to change the open graph tags for Facebook (& c:o) for different URL's on single page applications?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the mata tags this way:

```
$('meta[property=og:title]').attr("content", "new content");
$('meta[property=og:type]').attr("content", "new content");
```

and so on..?

```
$(element).bind("click", function(){
    $('meta[property=og:title]').attr("content", "new content");
    $('meta[property=og:type]').attr("content", "new content");
    // ....
    // Do share action
});
```

Comment: thanks for your code it does work when I viewed source but when I click share it do send the old open graph protocol It seem's that facebook cache problem on this.. .is there are possible to do change open graph protocol value on time on share button?